# run jenkins script remotely via PHP

Tags: php, jenkins, jenkins-php

I wrote a PHP script to run Jenkins build . It was working fine but now I applied some security and created users that can run jenkins builds.

```
<?php
   echo "Run Jenkins\n";
echo shell_exec("curl -X POST http://198.0.0.21:8080/job/test/build");
echo "\n\n";
?>
```

Now I have a user e.g. `test` and with password `test` .
How Can I rewrite my `PHP` script to use this user as authentication to run builds

I get the following output when I run the above script:

```
Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
```

I found the solution:

```
$u="test";
$p="test";
echo shell_exec("curl -X POST http://$u:$p@198.0.0.21:8080/job/test/build");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the version of jenkins you are running is greater than 1.426, you can generate a token to use in place of password so that you aren't revealing your password in plaintext.

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

Comment: Hi. Im using :  1.609.1 and token functionality does not work!!